# Get meta data and MRL from YouTube, SoundCloud, and other platforms

Tags: python, web-scraping, stream, urllib, libvlc

Currently I am using LibVLC to get the metadata and [MRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_resource_locator) of online *videos* and *music*.

But this is a lot of stupid overhead just to get this information.

```py
...
from vlc import Instance as vlcInstance, MediaList, MediaListPlayer, Event, EventType, State
...
self.player = MediaListPlayer(vlcInstance(options))
...
        self.list = MediaList(self._mrls)
        self.player.set_media_list(self.list)
...
        media = self.player.get_media_player().get_media()
        if media.get_meta(1) is not None and self.trackChangedEventCallback is not None:
            self.trackChangedEventCallback(
                media.get_meta(0),  # Title
                media.get_meta(1),  # Artist
                media.get_meta(6),  # Description
                media.get_meta(10), # URL
                media.get_meta(15)  # Artlink
            )
        print(media.get_mrl()) # MRL
...
```

Of course, there are packages for different platforms, but I don't want to replace one stupid overhead with another one.
I have taken a quick look into the youtube.lua script of VLC, but I have not found a good idea. How does LibVLC do this parsing to get the meta and mrl?

Web scraping was another idea, but seems not very reliable to me at this point.

So how can I do the same as my LibVLC-Code without using a huge overhead? Hopefully, there is a `urllib` based working solution or something else.

Possible duplicate: *[How can I parse YouTube and SoundCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322391/how-can-i-parse-youtube-and-soundcloud)*

Comment: If the question is a duplicate then please close it as such.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, I decided to use [youtube_dl](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl), because it is very easy to use and supports a lot of platforms: http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html

Here is my example code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import youtube_dl as ydl

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qEzh3wKVJc"

with ydl.YoutubeDL(
    {
        "forcejson": True,
        "noplaylist": True,
        "format": "bestaudio"
    }
) as parser:
    meta = parser.extract_info(
        url,
        download=False
    )

print(meta['thumbnail'])
print(meta['title'])
print(meta['url'])
```